# Google API Gateway: Assign config via gcloud CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-gateway

I'm looking for a way to automate config updates for Google API Gateway, i.e. change config for an existing instance of "API Gateway" in a single step.

What I've tried so far, assuming that new API config name is "my-new-config" and API Gateway name is "my-gateway":

1. `> gcloud beta api-gateway gateways update my-gateway --api-config=my-new-config --location=us-central1`
   Output:
   `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.api-gateway.gateways.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: update_mask does not contain any field paths`
2. `> gcloud beta api-gateway gateways update my-gateway --api-config=my-new-config --location=us-central1 --display-name random-string-for-display-name`
   Output:
   Command executes successfully, but config change is not applied.

gcloud version: 333.0.0
OS: Debian linux
I've created 2 tickets in Google's issue tracker ([one](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/181709339), [two](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/181415194)), but there's no activity for them after 3 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

You try to update `api-config` of `api-gateway`, here `api` is a required flag:

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/api-gateway/gateways/update), when first is specified, second is mandatory:

```
[--api-config=API_CONFIG : --api=API]
```

> `api-config`: This flag must be specified if any of the other arguments in this group are specified.

After i've added `--api`, it was possible to update the gateway with the new `api-config`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `aplha` instead of `beta` and specifying de API ID flag (`--api`):

`gcloud alpha api-gateway gateways update my-gateway --api=api-id --api-config=my-new-config --location=us-central1`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `--api` flag in step 2, which seems to be required. It looks like without that specified, it doesn't make the right request.